# Table containing radio button is stretched in Firefox and mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, html-table

I have a table containing one row with "fixed" content, and then a certain amount of rows containing content from a database. The first 3 `<td>`, in each row, contains a radio button each, which is part of a form. My problem is that these fields containing the radio buttons is making the table stretch, which makes the other fields too small. Please see my attached photo (first one from Mac Safari/Chrome and the second from Firefox):

In Chrome:

[image]

In Firefox:

[image]

Below is the part of my code, which prints the radio buttons. I have all the required start and close parts of tr, td, table, form etc. The php variable, which is printed as the name of the radio button, simply contains an integer and no other characters.

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="tg-s6z2"><input type="radio" name="'.$koncerter->kon_id.'" value="0" checked /></td>';
echo '<td class="tg-s6z2"><input type="radio" name="'.$koncerter->kon_id.'" value="1" /></td>';
echo '<td class="tg-s6z2"><input type="radio" name="'.$koncerter->kon_id.'" value="2" /></td>';
```

Any suggestions to, how I can fix this issue?
I also tried adding this to the surrounding div container:

```
<div class="content" style="max-width:650px;">
```

Comment: I should also note that the problem doesn't occur if I remove the radio buttons and replace them with some text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since when you remove the radio button it gets back to normal, then you probably have a CSS declaration for `input` that has a width (like 300px width). So simply remove that width, or do this:

```
input[type="radio"]{width:30px; /*or whatever */}
```

or this: Remove the styling for inputs and then target only the ones you need

```
input[type="text"]{width:120px; /*or whatever */}
```

In the first case, we'll add a style ONLY for radio. In the second option, we're resetting styles and then only styling those elements you need